# Validating Controller classes in java using @Pattern annotation for multiple strings

Tags: java, validation, design-patterns, controller, deadbolt

I am validating a java class using @Pattern annotation from Deadbolt. I want to give access if either of these strings are present : 'TM_TASK' OR 'TM_CHECKLIST'. Right now i am a little confused as to how to provide these strings inside @Pattern so that it gives access if the string matches either of those 2 strings.I am also open to using regex (although i am new to them) as to how to verify if it is any of those 2 strings ('TM_TASK' OR 'TM_CHECKLIST') using Regex and not any other invalid string.

e.g.

```
@Api(value = "/tasks")
@Pattern(value = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", patternType = PatternType.REGEX)
public class TaskController extends BaseController {

  private static Logger.ALogger log = Logger.of(TaskController.class);
  private TaskService taskService;
  private FormFactory formFactory;
}
```

Comment: Anybody has any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard regex of `(TM_TASK|TM_CHECKLIST)` to do this.

```
@Api(value = "/tasks")
@Pattern(value = "^(TM_TASK|TM_CHECKLIST)$", patternType = PatternType.REGEX)
public class TaskController extends BaseController {

  private static Logger.ALogger log = Logger.of(TaskController.class);
  private TaskService taskService;
  private FormFactory formFactory;
}
```

Comment: No the regex does not work. It could not access the controller methods(which is otherwise accessible) even if the user has "TM_CHECKLIST" permission. The same case happens for "TM_TASK" .May be the @Pattern doesn't validate such expressions. Any other solution ?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-java-examples/blob/master/app/controllers/PatternController.java#L44).  The most likely explanation is the permissions you're returning from `Subject#getPermissions()`  don't match your regex.  Set a breakpoint in `be.objectify.deadbolt.java.ConstraintLogic#pattern` to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: Ya...now it's working.Actually had forgotten to add the pattern type with the pattern inside the annotation.

Comment: @SouravBebarta if your question is answered, please mark the reply as accepted to help other people.

Comment: My reputation being less than 15, the post score isn't updated publicly although recorded.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to form the regex in Pattern annotation in case my requirement is validation of both strings (TM_TASK and TM_CHECKLIST) separately in any order.How to have the AND condition ?

Comment: Which version of Deadbolt are you using?

Comment: I am using deadbolt 2.6.1

Comment: You can use composite constraints to do this.  Take a look at https://deadbolt-java.readme.io/docs/composite-constraints